# copy an array from x to y not x to array.length

Tags: c#, arrays, split

I've tried copying arrays in such a way I can crunch data in an array with threads but obviously without splitting the array into smaller chunks (lets say 1 array -> 4 quarters (4 arrays)).

The only method I can find copies from a specified (int)start point and copies all leading data from the start to the end which if I am using multiple threads to crunch the data its nullifies the point of threading.

Here is pseudo code to show what I wish to do.

```
int array { 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15 }
int split1 { 0, 1, 2, 3 }
int split2 { 4, 5, 6, 7 }
int split3 { 8, 9, 10, 11 }
int split4 { 12, 13, 14, 15 }
```

or lets say the length of the array cant be split up evenly

```
int array { 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16 }
int split1 { 0, 1, 2, 3 }
int split2 { 4, 5, 6, 7 }
int split3 { 8, 9, 10, 11 }
int split4 { 12, 13, 14, 15, 16}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> The only method I can find copies from a specified (int)start point and copies all leading data from the start to the end which if I am using multiple threads to crunch the data its nullifies the point of threading.

It's a shame you didn't show which method that was. [`Array.Copy`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.array.copy.aspx) has various overloads for copying *part* of an array to another array. [This one](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/z50k9bft.aspx) is probably the most helpful:

```
public static void Copy(
    Array sourceArray,
    int sourceIndex,
    Array destinationArray,
    int destinationIndex,
    int length
)
```

Alternatively, look at [`Buffer.BlockCopy`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.buffer.blockcopy.aspx), which has basically the same signature - but the values are all in terms of *bytes* rather than array indexes. It also only works with arrays of primitives.

Another alternative would be not to create copies of the array at all - if each thread knows which segment of the array it should work with, it can access that directly. You should also look into [`Parallel.ForEach`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.tasks.parallel.foreach.aspx) (and similar methods) as a way of parallelizing operations easily at a higher level.

Comment: Ah that's where I was going wrong I was using variable.copyTo() not Array.Copy() thanks